# ios detect a false change in wireless - Reachability Example

Tags: objective-c, ios, network-programming, ios6, reachability

My Application use Wifi network and I am using Reachability example code to detect the Wifi network.

Application works well when app is connected to any normal Wifi Access Point but my app detects false network change when app is connected to Ad-hoc network.

When App is connected to ad-hoc network, after some time (around every 15 to 20 minutes) current reachability status goes to **Not Reachable** for few seconds and comeback again to **Reachable** state (FYI, Similar Android App is working fine on same Ad-hoc network).

**Debug Information**

Reachability Flag Status: -- -------

After 1 or 2 seconds Wifi return to normal status

Reachability Flag Status: -R ------d

**Code**

```
    - (NetworkStatus) currentReachabilityStatus{
        NSAssert(reachabilityRef != NULL, @"currentNetworkStatus called with NULL reachabilityRef");
        NetworkStatus retVal = NotReachable;
        SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
        if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags))
        {
            if(localWiFiRef)
            {
                retVal = [self localWiFiStatusForFlags: flags];
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = [self networkStatusForFlags: flags];
            }
        }
        if(NotReachable == retVal){
            printf("\nNetwork not reachable.");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: So you are sure the result is wrong because you have tried another platform that has different results - think again.

Comment: Hey my app also facing the same issue... did you get any solution over this??